How to migrate one aws app to another aws app
I have an existing aws amplify project, now I want a copy of that project and I want to deploy it (version 2). I have created a new backend now I want to push all the existing backend to this new copy.
I tried to amplify pull using my appid, but it gave error Amplify appId mismatch.
